# Realm Swift Migration: How to see if property/key exists?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got a iOS based realm app that has gone through a number of schema changes.  For one schema version (version 36), I added a property named "activationStartGameTime" as a swift `TimeInterval?` (which is basically a `Double`) on a class `Period`.  In a later schema version (version 38) I changed that property to an `Int?`.  I have this in my migration:

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 38) {
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Period.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        if let startTimeInterval = oldObject?["activationStartGameTime"] as? TimeInterval {
            newObject!["activationStartGameTime"] = Int(startTimeInterval)
        } else {
            newObject!["activationStartGameTime"] = nil
        }
    ...
```

For users who have received all versions of that app (specifically if they get a version of the app that has realm schema 36 or 37, they're fine since in the property `activationStartGameTime` was added.  However, when a user who is using a version of the app that has schema version < 36 tries to upgrade to the current app (schema version 38), they're getting a crash because the line

```
        if let startTimeInterval = oldObject?["activationStartGameTime"] as? TimeInterval {
```

is crashing.  It seems that looking for a non-existant key by using `oldObject?["some_non_existant_key"]` always crashes with the error:

`2024-02-08 20:46:05.398426-0800 FooApp... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid property name 'activationStartGameTime' for class 'Period'.'`

I can't seem to find the magic incantation that will let me look for a property of an `oldObject` and not have it crash if the property does not exist.

(I'm on realm-swift 10.46.0, which is the latest as of 2024_02_08)

Any ideas?

Comment: The question is a little vague. Are you asking about *adding* a new property to a Realm object or about migrating an existing Double to an Int? The latter would be an additionally migration step. One would be to migrate to 36 and then another step to migrate to 37. See the Linear Migration comment [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/change-an-object-model/#automatically-update-schema). e.g. it can't all be done within one `if oldSchemaVersion < x` -  it would require multiple to account for each version.